# ios/objective-c: Reference variable in method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

in one method, save, I set a property saveUnderway.

```
-(void) save {
BOOL saveUnderway=YES;
}
```

How would I reference this from another method in the same class?

```
-(void) someOtherMethod {
if ([self save.saveUnderway]==YES) { //this line throws error expected ']'
//do something
}
}
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid setting property in .h file.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: r u trying to set the bool value in save method from someother method ?

Comment: no retrieve it.  However, as per Joe's answer I guess I have to store it as an interface extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveUnderway is only available inside the scope of the -save method when its declared like this. If you don't want to set a property in the .h file you can setup an interface-extension inside of your .m file above you're @implementation call and declare the property there. It'll look something like this.

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL saveUnderway;    

@end
```

Then you can access this by calling self.saveUnderway

If you don't want to setup a property at all you can also declare variables like this

```
@implementation MyClass {
    BOOL _saveUnderway; // Convention usually has an _ before the variable name which is why I put it here.
}
```

Then you can access this by calling _saveUnderway inside any method in your class.

Comment: Thx.  Don't know why so many down votes.  saveUnderway may be useful when the user clicks twice on the save button.  It is useful to block a second save if the first save is already underway.

Comment: The down votes are because, from the way you asked the question, it looks like you have hardly any understanding of objective-c. You're trying to access the saveUnderway variable in a way that doesn't make any sense. A lot of people think the question isn't of very high quality because of that. Everyone starts somewhere though! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Joe Bell gave a good answer.

Keep in mind that if you want to use that bool value in other places, you can use NSUserDefaults to store something, but don't forget to reset that value so it doesn't messes things up.